# If I call an asyncTask from a thread will the onPostExecute() execute on the thread or the calling activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have my main application running. I then start a new thread.

In this thread i call an asyncTask.

Will its

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

method execute on the thread or on the application calling the thread?

Comment: Why don't you check it out by logging which thread it's on? My guess would be on the new thread

Comment: I would think the thread that called the execute method of the asynctask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) are very specific about this point:

- The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
- The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
- execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.

This is because the AsyncTask internally uses a Handler to do the communication with the Thread which called **new** and **execute()** on it. If this Thread is the UI-Thread, there is no problem. Otherwise the calling Thread has to be a Looper to be able to link UI changing operations and event handling with the UI-Thread.